How Can I use ACF Form in a shortcode?
I'm new to using ACF form and trying to create a form for users to submit a post using a shortcode. I don't particularly want to use a page template. The fields are an image field and 5 text fields. I am trying to display a success message once the form is submitted but I keep running into problems no matter what I try.
This is my current code:
function toyw_gallery_item_form_handler() {
    
    // Load ACF form header
    acf_form_head();
    
    ob_start();

    // ACF Form settings
    $settings = array(
        'id' => 'gallery_form',
        'post_id' => 'new_post',
        'post_title' => false,
        'new_post' => array('post_type' => 'gallery-item', 'post_status' => 'pending'),
        'field_groups' => array('group_66acdfbecde2d'),
        'submit_value' => __("Submit", 'acf'),
        'form_attributes' => array('class' => 'gallery_form'),
        'html_submit_button'  => '<input type="submit" class="acf-button button kb-button kt-button kt-btn-size-standard kt-btn-width-type-auto kb-btn-global-inherit" value="%s" />',
    );

    // Render the form
    acf_form($settings);
    
    return ob_get_clean();
}

When I add return => '' the form clears but no message is displayed, if I try to redirect to a different page I get the error of "cannot modify header information". I've tried adding the arguments for updated_message and html_updated_message but this doesn't work either. I've also tried to redirect using 'acf/save_post' instead but get the header information error again.
I am on WP 6.6.1 and using Kadence with a child theme.

acf_form_head() must load before get_header() so you need some additional checks to see if you need acf_form_head() in your template even if its default page.php . Thats why you get this error. If you want better answer check this - https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/create-front-end-form-using-shortcode/

you need to add a success message and redirection for that.
